# how to properly remove nodes once outside of scene

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody, skaction

[image: this is what they look like when stuck]I am making a game where the "arrow" in this case, is a node that falls every few seconds in a random area from top to bottom of the screen. The problem is that when the node reaches around the last 10th of the screen, it seems to almost get stuck on the screen, and stops, not fully going off the screen and disappearing. Is there any way to fix this?

```
func startTheArrow() {

    run(SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.sequence([SKAction.run(spawnArrow), SKAction.wait(forDuration: 5.0)])))
    
} 




func spawnArrow() {
    
    let arrow = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "arrow")
    
    arrow.size = CGSize(width: 50, height: 50)
    arrow.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: arrow.size)
    arrow.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    arrow.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = ColliderType.arrow
    
    arrow.name = "Arrow"
    
    arrow.zPosition = 1
    
    arrow.position = CGPoint(x: frame.size.width * random(min: -0.45, max: 0.45), y: frame.size.height * random(min: 0.6, max: 0.7))
    
    addChild(arrow)
    
    arrow.run(
        SKAction.moveBy(x: 0.0 , y: -size.height - arrow.size.height,
                        duration: TimeInterval(random(min: 2, max: 2))))
    
    self.enumerateChildNodes(withName: "Arrow") { (node:SKNode, nil) in
        if node.position.y < -500 || node.position.y > self.size.height + 550 {
            node.removeFromParent()
            
                 
       }
   }   
}
```

Comment: Check that the physics bodies are not colliding with something, turn them on by using  'view.showsPhysics = true' in your ViewController (same place as 'view.showsFPS = true' etc).

Comment: @JohnL Hey so never knew you could do that! I did, and nothing seems to show up as being there. It's very strange and I can't think of any reason why it would stop there.

Comment: are you using physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFrom: frame) ???

Comment: @SimonePistecchia no! and thats what is so odd! There shouldn't be any resistance there. Maybe its the way that I set up the SKView and presentScene in viewController?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally found the solution. For some reason, Xcode doesn't like this code:

```
arrow.run(
    SKAction.moveBy(x: 0.0 , y: -size.height - arrow.size.height, duration: TimeInterval(random(min: 2, max: 2))))
    self.enumerateChildNodes(withName: "Arrow") { (node:SKNode, nil) in
    if node.position.y < -500 || node.position.y > self.size.height + 550 {
        node.removeFromParent()
    }
}
```

I instead used the following code in place of this and the nodes were fixed, although they don't fully go off the screen, there isn't some weird stoppage and pileup at the bottom of the scene.

```
let moveEnemy = SKAction.moveTo(y: -800, duration: 4.0)
let deleteEnemy= SKAction.removeFromParent()
let enemySequence = SKAction.sequence([moveEnemy, deleteEnemy])
enemy.run(enemySequence)
```